# Reference is not a valid visual DependencyObject

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use the [coding4fun toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) for windows phone 7.

```
InputPrompt input = new InputPrompt();
whoAreYou.Completed += input_Completed;
input.Title = "Who are you?";
input.Message = "Enter your name";
input.Show();

void input_Completed(object sender, PopUpEventArgs<object, PopUpResult> e)
    {
        //add some code here   
        InputPrompt input = sender as InputPrompt;
       MessageBox.Show(input.Value);
    }
```

This throws the exception below:

```
Reference is not a valid visual DependencyObject
```

I want to ask the user for his/her name.
I'm following this [tutorial](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-InputPrompt-in-depth) and have added the necessary assembly references.
**How can I get the coding4fun toolkit to work?**

Edit:
If I do this in xaml like
`<c4f:InputPrompt x:Name="input" Completed="input_Completed_1" />`

Then this works, but I need it to work with code.

Comment: You mean the sender is null in the input_Completed? Because that would be an error in the source code. I've seen it more often that people call there delegates and send null as a sender instead of 'this'

Comment: No, it didn't get to the input_Completed. There was a problem in the call to `input.Show()`

Comment: @nikil Glad you have a working solution. Best regards.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on a random question, but you flagged a question regarding Way2sms, can you provide more information about where that limitation is stated? (I will delete this comment+responses when/if you respond)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reproduced your bug when I've added the code presented to the Main Page constructor. It seems like an InputPrompt isn't added to the visual tree (just a theory) and that's why can't be shown.

When I've changed the code to show InputPrompt upon Loaded event, everything worked fine. Basically, you have to wait until the page is loaded or put the control in your XAML file.

Comment: In your constructor, put up following code: this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);

and then use MainPage_Loaded method to show InputPrompt.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was most helpful.

Comment: Same issue to me, when show AboutPrompt dialog in Main Constructor, then I use your method of this.Load. Great! it works, thanks.